# Split string in to array

Tags: ruby, string, ruby-on-rails-3

Input:

```
2014-09-16T05:59:43,274     17898026714983488   127.0.0.1   /banner b=123&c=test&p=45   host:test.google.com|x-forwarded-for:182.65.228.222|accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8|user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36|accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8|cookie:_ga=GA1.2.1550976853.1405927868; __gads=ID=058659026f235a09:T=1409198510:S=ALNI_MambZn0wB2dVEwa4AbsP2Mok728qQ
```

Expected values:

```
 [2014-09-16T05:59:43,274   ,
    17898026714983488,
    127.0.0.1,
    /banner,
    b=123&c=test&p=45 ,
    host:test.google.co,
    x-forwarded-for:182.65.228.22,
    accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.,
    user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916153 fari/537.36|accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.,
    cookie:_ga=GA1.2.1550976853.05927868;__gads=ID=058659026f235a09:T=1409198510:S=ALNI_MambZn0wB2dVEwa4AbsP2Mok728q]
```

Is there any way store the each value in to an array in ruby ?

Comment: What is "each value" ?

Comment: @Santosh I updated expected values. Kindly take a look.

Comment: I know some better way.. Could you tell me how are you getting this value ?

Comment: This values are written in log file.

Comment: Are those response data ?

Comment: Yes,, you can handle it different way.. Play with this [request object](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object).. This will help you.. I am sure.. Regex is not comfortable stuffs in this case.

Comment: You're basically asking [how to split string by whitespace in Ruby](https://www.google.de/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=how+to+split+string+by+whitespace+in+Ruby&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=WDUhVOSHEKmF8Qfc2oGIDw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is will work *at-least for the given example* but you may need to tweak for more stable results:

```
split('|').each_with_index.map {|element, index| index == 0 ? element.split : element }.flatten
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the method .split() for strings